# How to fetch the last value from the list of values using RegEx?

Tags: regex, drupal, preg-match

I'm trying to get the latest version i.e. **2.4** using regex from the below mentioned code.

```
//Version 1.0 Aug 31st 2011 -First Release.
//Version 1.1 Sep 29th 2011 
//Bug fixed: When using hovercard in hovercard, the inner hovercard shows up as well when parent hovercard opens.
//
//Version 1.2 Sep 30th 2011
//Enhancement: The hovercard now adjust (either open on left or right) in accordance to the view port.
//Added options:
//openOnLeft: force hovercard to open on left. (eg: if the hovered name appear in the end of sentence)
//
//Version 2.0 Nov 8th 2011
//Bug Fixes: zindex issue.
//Enhancements: Supercool built in social profile cards like Twitter and Facebook!
//Added options:
//showTwitterCard: displays a built in twitter card format for a twitter screenname. Maximum 150 twitter lookup per hour.
//twitterScreenName: twitter screen name for the hovercard. If no username/screenname is provided, hovercard attempts to look up for hovered text.
//showFacebookCard: displays a built in facebook card format for a facebook username/pages/events etc. Works best with Facebook pages.
//facebookUserName: facebook username/pages/events/groups for the hovercard. If no username is provided, hovercard attempts to look up for hovered text.
//
//Version 2.1 Nov 22nd 2011
//Enhancement: attribute 'data-hovercard'. You may now use data-hovercard attribute with your label/link etc to set the twitter or facebook usernames.
//Added options:
//showCustomCard: You may now add your own custom data source and display the profile data using existing card format.
//
//Version 2.2 Dec 9th 2011
//Bug Fixes: zindex issue with IE7.
//
//Version 2.3 Dec 15th 2011
//Enhancement: The plugin now auto adjust on the edges of visible window/viewport!
//Added options:
//openOnTop: Set 'openOnTop' to true if you want the hovercard to always open on left.
//customCardJSON: Provide a local json data with showCustomCard. Inherits plugin's social card format/styles.
//delay: Delay the hovercard appearance on hover.
//
//Version 2.4 Apr 12th 2012
//Added options:
//autoAdjust: The plugin's default functionality to auto adjust to the viewport edges can now be overridden.
```

Currently, I'm executing this `@(?i:Version) ([0-9]+ )@` which is providing me an output of **1.0** its nothing but the first matched value, how can I get the last matched value?

## Update:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_libraries_info().
 */
function hover_card_libraries_info() {
  $libraries['hover_card'] = array(
    'name' => 'Hover Card Plugin',
    'vendor url' => 'http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard',
    'download url' => 'https://github.com/prashantchaudhary/hovercard/archive/master.zip',
    'version arguments' => array(
      'file' => 'jquery.hovercard.js',
      'pattern' => '@(?i:Version) ([0-9\.a-z]+)@',
    ),
    'files' => array(
      'js' => array(
        'jquery.hovercard.min.js',
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $libraries;
}
```

I've tried both code & they didn't work, since the **pattern** which Drupal is following is bit different. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex to get the last Version number from the log file.

```
(?s).*Version (\S+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sQ0kW4/3)

Version number would be stored in the first captured group. It could be possible through `(?s)`(DOTALL) modifier.

```
$regex = '~(?s).*Version (\S+)~';
if (preg_match($regex, $mystring, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[1]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
```

OR

```
(?s).*Version\s*\K\S+
```

Your PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$mystring = <<< 'EOT'
//Version 1.0 Aug 31st 2011 -First Release.
//Version 1.1 Sep 29th 2011 
//Bug fixed: When using hovercard in hovercard, the inner hovercard shows up as well when parent hovercard opens.
//
//Version 1.2 Sep 30th 2011
//Enhancement: The hovercard now adjust (either open on left or right) in accordance to the view port.
//Added options:
//openOnLeft: force hovercard to open on left. (eg: if the hovered name appear in the end of sentence)
//
//Version 2.0 Nov 8th 2011
//Bug Fixes: zindex issue.
//Enhancements: Supercool built in social profile cards like Twitter and Facebook!
//Added options:
//showTwitterCard: displays a built in twitter card format for a twitter screenname. Maximum 150 twitter lookup per hour.
//twitterScreenName: twitter screen name for the hovercard. If no username/screenname is provided, hovercard attempts to look up for hovered text.
//showFacebookCard: displays a built in facebook card format for a facebook username/pages/events etc. Works best with Facebook pages.
//facebookUserName: facebook username/pages/events/groups for the hovercard. If no username is provided, hovercard attempts to look up for hovered text.
//
//Version 2.1 Nov 22nd 2011
//Enhancement: attribute 'data-hovercard'. You may now use data-hovercard attribute with your label/link etc to set the twitter or facebook usernames.
//Added options:
//showCustomCard: You may now add your own custom data source and display the profile data using existing card format.
//
//Version 2.2 Dec 9th 2011
//Bug Fixes: zindex issue with IE7.
//
//Version 2.3 Dec 15th 2011
//Enhancement: The plugin now auto adjust on the edges of visible window/viewport!
//Added options:
//openOnTop: Set 'openOnTop' to true if you want the hovercard to always open on left.
//customCardJSON: Provide a local json data with showCustomCard. Inherits plugin's social card format/styles.
//delay: Delay the hovercard appearance on hover.
//
//Version 2.4 Apr 12th 2012
//Added options:
//autoAdjust: The plugin's default functionality to auto adjust to the viewport edges can now be overridden.
EOT;
$regex = '~(?s).*Version\s*\K\S+~';
if (preg_match($regex, $mystring, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
?> //=> 2.4
```

Comment: I've to use it something like this `'pattern' => '(?s).*Version \K\S+'` and it didn't worked. Some more suggestions?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention the source file is from JS, but when I tried your code in my PHP file `'pattern' => '@(~(?s).*Version \K\S+~)@'` I'm still getting a blank output.

Comment: change the pattern to `'~(?s).*Version\s*\K\S+~'`

Comment: Thanks, I tried it as `'pattern' => '~(?s).*Version\s*\K\S+~'` but still no output but when I tried it as `'pattern' => '@((?s).*Version (\S+))@'` I'm getting output as '//Version 1.0', any suggestions?

Comment: use this pattern `@(?s).*Version (\S+)@` and print the match group 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58156/discussion-between-rishi-kulshreshtha-and-avinash-raj).